# drawnow performance/plot speed

Tags: matlab, drawnow

I am life plotting a dataset for creating hysteresis loops. I agreed with the plot speed before but since I added the scatter it got really slow.

The scatter adds a marker to the current plotted datapoint so that if the plot overwrites you can still pursuite the animated line.

Here is my code:

```
hAL = animatedline;  % line handle
hAL.LineStyle='-';
hAL.Color='blue';
% defaults for the marker
hAx=gca;      % get the axis handle
sz=10;        % size of marker
clr='b';      % color
hS=scatter(hAx,nan,nan,sz,clr);  % initial point won't show but creates handle
x = mmatrix(:,2);
y = mmatrix(:,1);
for k = 1:length(x)
  addpoints(hAL,x(k),y(k));
  set(hS,'xdata',x(k),'ydata',y(k))  % update the marker position
  drawnow
end
```

Do you know of an option to regulate the plot speed? 
I tried `drawnow limitrate` but it's to fast.

Regards jw

Comment: What is `mmatrix`?

Comment: `mmatrix` is the dataset for the plot, containing `Sig-Eps` values for the hysteresis loops plot

Comment: Please see: [mcve]

Comment: If you want to slow it down you can always put something like `pause(0.1)` immediately after the `drawnow`.  (Making the input to pause smaller will speed up the rendering, while making it larger will slow it down.)

Comment: yes indeed. i add pause after `drawnow limitrate`. that works!